# md-datepicker after select date and submission of form invalid date error in mozilla firefox only

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, datepicker

Using md-min-date and md-max-date allow picking dates when using the datepicker, after pick date and submit the form then invalid date error coming in Mozilla firefox only Remaining browsers working.

Basically just used the demo code and added a button. 
Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwaJvQ

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" name="updateProductionForm">
                <div class="form-group row">

                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 control-label">
                  Start Date</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <md-datepicker style="background: none;" ng-model="dialogCtrl.production.productionStartDate" ng-change="editRequestCtrl.changeDays()" md-placeholder="Enter Start Date" required md-min-date="dialogCtrl.production.productionStartDate" md-max-date="dialogCtrl.production.productionEndDate"></md-datepicker>
                  </div>
                </div>    
                <div class="form-group row">

                  <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 control-label">
                  End Date</label>
                  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                    <md-datepicker ng-model="dialogCtrl.production.productionEndDate" md-placeholder="Enter End Date" required md-min-date="dialogCtrl.production.productionStartDate" md-max-date="dialogCtrl.production.productionEndDate"></md-datepicker>
                  </div>
                </div>                
                <div class="form-group">
           <button type="submit" class="bordered-btn white-bg" ng-disabled="updateProductionForm.$invalid" ng-click="dialogCtrl.updateProduction()">Update</button>
                </div>
              </form>
```

any idea to resolve this compatibility issue?